# Вывести цвет, который максимальное количество раз идет подряд, либо в ряде, либо в столбце

Tags: python

Есть двумерный список:

```
color_chains = [
    ["green", "yellow", "blue", "red", "green"],
    ["green", "yellow", "blue", "red", "yellow"],
    ["blue", "yellow", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
    ["green", "yellow", "red", "red", "red"]
]
```

В данном случает ответ должен быть `yellow`.

Я решил эту задачу так:

```
def count_max_chain(chain_of_colors):
    max_count_same_color_row = 1
    count_same_color_row = 1

    max_count_same_color_column = 1
    count_same_color_column = 1

    previous_color = None
    row_result = {}
    column_result = {}

    # самое длинное в ряде
    for row in chain_of_colors:
        for color in row:

            if color == previous_color:
                count_same_color_row += 1
            else:
                previous_color = color
                count_same_color_row = 1

            if count_same_color_row > max_count_same_color_row:
                max_count_same_color_row = count_same_color_row
                row_result = {color: max_count_same_color_row}
        count_same_color_row = 1

    # самое длинное в колонне
    max_len_row = 0
    previous_color = None
    index_color = 0
    for row in chain_of_colors:
        if len(row) > max_len_row: max_len_row = len(row)

    while index_color <= max_len_row:
        for row in chain_of_colors:
            try:
                if row[index_color] == previous_color:
                    count_same_color_column += 1
                    if count_same_color_column > max_count_same_color_column:
                        column_result = {}
                        max_count_same_color_column = count_same_color_column
                        column_result[row[index_color]] = max_count_same_color_column
                else:
                    previous_color = row[index_color]
                    count_same_color_column = 1
            except:
                pass
        index_color += 1

    if max_count_same_color_column > max_count_same_color_row:
        print(column_result)
    else:
        print(row_result)

count_max_chain(color_chains)
```

Но уверен, что есть более изящный метод. Можете его подсказать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Хз, сложная какая-то здесь вставка.

Comment: Да, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насколько это *"изящно"*, но, как вариант, можно вот так:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

color_chains = [["green", "yellow", "blue", "red" , "green" ],
                ["green", "yellow", "blue", "red" , "yellow"],
                ["blue" , "yellow", "blue", "blue", "blue"  ],
                ["green", "yellow", "red" , "red" , "red"   ]]

def count_max_chain(chain_of_colors):
    def max_chain_in_row(row):
        res = []
        for item in row:
            res.append((res[-1][0]+1, item) if res and res[-1][1] == item else (1,item))
        return max(res)

    return max(max_chain_in_row(row) for row in chain(chain_of_colors, zip(*chain_of_colors)))[1]

print(count_max_chain(color_chains))
```

Функция `max_chain_in_row(row)` обрабатывает ряд и подсчитывает в нём повторяющиеся элементы. Например, для нижеприведённого ряда будет такое преобразование:
`["blue" , "yellow", "blue", "blue", "blue"]`
v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v v  v v v v v v v v
`[(1,"blue") , (1,"yellow"), (1,"blue"), (2,"blue"), (3,"blue")]`.
И в конце возвращает кортеж с максимальным значением.

Ну а общая функция собирает в общий список результаты обработки рядов исходного списка списков плюс рядов транспонированной матрицы `zip(*chain_of_colors)` (это исходный список где столбцы стали рядами и наоборот (чтобы не заморачиваться и всегда работать с рядами) и опять берёт максимум.
*(Если в конце последнего `return` убрать `[1]`, то функция вернёт кортеж `(количество, цвет)`.)*

---

Если ряды могут быть не одинаковой длины, то с минимальными модификациями функция будет выглядеть так:

```
def count_max_chain(chain_of_colors):
    def max_chain_in_row(row):
        res = []
        for item in row:
            res.append((res[-1][0]+1, item) if item and res and res[-1][1] == item else res[-1] if item is None else (1,item))
        return max(res)

    return max(max_chain_in_row(row) for row in chain(chain_of_colors, zip_longest(*chain_of_colors)))[1]
```

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит и правда лаконичней.